# SQL Server 2008 x64 R2 SP1 - Management Studio installation language

Tags: sql-server-2008, language

In our production server, the hosting provider installed SQL Server and Management Studio (standard edition) in Spanish, but I would like to have them in English. It's quite difficult to find menu options in the Spanish version, which is very poorly translated.

When I try to install the same version of Management Studio (although in English), the installer says the language of the installed version does not match the installer.

I thought I could uninstall the Management Studio in Spanish in order to install the English version, but there is no clear uninstall option in the setup.

Is there a way to replace the Management Studio with the English version WITHOUT uninstalling SQL Server? This is a production server, 24/365, so I cannot afford the down time of reinstalling the whole product.

The server is a Windows 2008 Server x64 (Spanish) with the English language pack, and the database is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 x64 R2 SP1 (Standard).

Thanks in advance,
Guillermo